# how to delete all cookies of different path under a domain

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, servlets, cookies

Cookie[] cookies=request.getCookies();

```
for(Cookie cookie:cookies)
{
cookie.setMaxAge(0);
cookie.setValue(null);
cookie.setPath("/");
response.addCookie(cookie); 
}
```

I used this code to delete all cookies from browser,some cookies having path("/") sets to null, it expires also but some cookie having path **(/xyz)** doesn't gets change

Please help me to delete all cookies from the browser at one short, when the user logs out from my application.

Comment: Do those cookies with path `(/xyz)` have the same name as the ones with path `/`?

Comment: Nope names are different

Comment: `request.getCookies();` gets all the Cookies that are sent by the browser to the Server. Check if the cookies you expect are getting returned, Cookies set by a different Server will not be returned to this Server. If you are trying something like that then you must do it in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you.

```
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class CookiesUtil {

  public static final int COOKIE_DEFAULT_AGE = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60; // 30天
  private static final String COOKIE_DOMAIN = ".domain.com";
  private static final String COOKIE_PATH = "/";

  public static void removeCookie(String cookieName, HttpServletResponse response) {
    removeCookie(cookieName, COOKIE_DOMAIN, COOKIE_PATH, response);
  }

  /**
   * remove cookie
   * @param cookieName
   * @param domain
   * @param response
   */
  private static void removeCookie(String cookieName, String domain,
      String path, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(cookieName, "");
    cookie.setPath(path);
    cookie.setDomain(domain);
    cookie.setMaxAge(0);
    response.addCookie(cookie);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,Your code helps to expires the coockie having same path ( "/ " )  what about other path coockie

Comment: this is a generic solution for the problem which you can use for various urls..thank you